# Where are ethernet/internet/networking configuration files/settings stored on OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, network, macbook-pro, ethernet

Someone I know has an ethernet configuration profile that works on the university network I'm on. As I am on 10.8 I do not have the option of configuring these files so I'd like to copy his Configuration Profile.

Where are these located on OS X 10.6?

Ps. I'm using a Macbook Air with a USB ethernet plug if that matters.

Psps. I know one can create profiles with the ipcu, but I haven't been able to make one that works for ethernet unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`

Comment: For 10.10 they're specifically named here as a subset of files in that dir: http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/11/wi-fi-problems-mac-os-x-yosemite.html  . In 10.12 they're different again compared to that, at least missing "com.apple.network.identification.plist" . Looks like "Locations" are ~mostly defined in "preferences.plist".